# How to split Xaml Grid column 50/50 when the 2nd column's content is visible?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, grid

With a grid that has 2 columns, how will I be able to split it 50/50 in width only when the content of the second column is visible?

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition />
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

   <Grid Grid.Column="0">
      <!-- Some content here -->
   </Grid>

   <Grid Grid.Column="1" Visibility="{Binding HasValue, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
      <!-- Some content here -->
   </Grid>    
</Grid>
```

If `HasValue` is true, the grid needs to be split 50/50, else, the first column must occupy the whole screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a converter *BoolToGridLengthConverter* and put it in your `App.xaml` as a static resource:

```
/// <summary>
/// Converts a boolean value to a grid length which is specified with a converter
/// parameter if the value is true, otherwise the grid lengthe will be zero.
/// <para>
/// If no parameter is specified the returned <see cref="Windows.UI.Xaml.GridLength"/> will be zero.
/// If the parameter cannot be parsed to a grid length then the returned <see cref="Windows.UI.Xaml.GridLength"/> will be zero.
/// If the value is a <see cref="bool"/> false, then the returned <see cref="Windows.UI.Xaml.GridLength"/> will be zero.
/// </para>
/// </summary>
public sealed class BoolToGridLengthConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (!(value is bool) || !(parameter is string))
        {
            return new GridLength(0);
        }

        if (!((bool)value))
        {
            return new GridLength(0);
        }

        var str = parameter as string;
        if (str.Equals("Auto"))
        {
            return new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Auto);
        }

        if (str.Equals("*"))
        {
            return new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
        }

        if (str.EndsWith("*"))
        {
            var length = Double.Parse(str.Substring(0, str.Length - 1));
            return new GridLength(length, GridUnitType.Star);
        }

        var len = Double.Parse(str);
        return new GridLength(len);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then you can use it in your xaml like this:

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding HasValue, Converter={StaticResource BoolToGridLengthConverter}, ConverterParameter='*'}"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Column="0">
            <!--  Some content here  -->
        </Grid>

        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Visibility="{Binding HasValue, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
            <!--  Some content here  -->
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

The converter will use the `ConverterParameter` only if the boolean value is `true`, otherwise the column width will be set to zero. The converter parameter, can by `Auto`, or for example `0.5*` or any fixed width for example `50.5` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use an asterisk for the width like below. If you have two they will share but if only one has content it should fill the space of the second.

`<ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>`

Comment: Both of the columns will have contents, the second column can be visible/collapsed. I want the first column to occupy the second column space if the content of the 2nd column is collapsed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late and I myself had to search a long time for a solution, but I hope that by the way I answer it, it will be understandable or future searchers. (I am using WPF.)

The best option to have two grids side-by-side and have them occupy a certain space that is in relation to each other takes a bit from the upper 2 answers.

You need:

1. 2 ColumnDefinitions that define the Widths.
2. 1 Binding, that is set in the code-behind by the HasValue-Binding.

In the XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width={Binding WidthDg2}/>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinition/>
    <DataGrid Grid.Column="0" ...>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            ...
        <DataGrid.Columns/>
    <DataGrid/>
    <DataGrid Grid.Column="1" Visibility={Binding HasValue}>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            ...
        <DataGrid.Columns/>
    <DataGrid/>
<Grid/>
```

In the C# code:

```
...
#region Properties
private Boolean _hasValue;
public Boolean HasValue
{
    get => _hasValue;
    set
    {
        _hasValue = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

private string _widthDg2;
public string WidthDg2
{
    get => HasValue ? "*" : "0";
    set
    {
        _widthDg2 = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
#endregion Properties
...
```

Context:

DataGrid (DG)'s width will always be its "x*", which means x (a natural number or 0) parts of y (sum of all "x*") available space units. Therefore if we set DG 1 to "2*" and DG 2 to "5*", DG 1 will automatically occupy a space of 2/7 and DG 2 will take up 5/7. This would also work with more DataGrids.

For your problem:

DataGrid 1's width is always "*". If HasValue is true WidthDg2 is also "*", which results in both DataGrid's taking 1/2 space each. If HasValue is false WidthDg2 will be set to "0", automatically causing DataGrid 1 to take up the whole 1 units of 1 available space unit, since Datagrid needs 0 space.